# two scrollbars on centrally divided layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a centrally divided layout using bootstrap.
the left side of the screen should be fixed and the right side of the screen should be scrollable.

It works fine so far, but when I test the layout on small devices, the right part of the screen gets two scrollbars.
When I hide the scrollbar on small devices, the content on the right side is not scrollable any more.

changing `overflow:auto;` to `overflow:visible;` solves the problem with two scrollbars, but the left side of the screen is not fixed any more and scrolls with the right side.
`position:fixed;` doesn't solve the problem.

here is the code:

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }

body {
  
  margin:  0;
}

#left {
  
  background-color:  yellow;
  height:  100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vw;
}

.container_left {
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#question {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#tip {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 #right{
   overflow: hidden;
 } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="left">
      <div class="container_left">
      <p id="question">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p id="tip">tip</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="right">
      <p style="color:red">start</p>
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
      <p style="color:red">end</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate your advice.

best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this css to hide the scrollbar in your second block. This will hide the scrollbar in that individual element but keep the site's main scrollbar:

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Note that this won't have full browser support.

Another, better solution would be to rework your html/css in general so that the first block is set in a fixed position while the remainder of the page scrolls as normal. This will have wider support across platforms. This way you're not fiddling with scroll bars.